# date is not printing properly for UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I have a date picker & above it I have 1 button as Done. On clicking this button I print the date picker date.

When I scroll the date picker and print date, it works fine. Below is the code I have

```
print("date selected===\(myDatePicker.date)")
```

The problem comes when I don't scroll the datepicker and click done button.

The scenario is I have set datepicker maximumDate as year 2000 (currentYear-18). Below is code I have used.

```
var dayComp = DateComponents()
currDate = Date()
dayComp.year = -18
currDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dayComp, to: currDate)!
mDateFrom.maximumDate = currDate
```

Now as datepicker is going back 18 years, I see date picker with date as 25/Jul/2000 however when I click Done button it print today date only.

It gives proper date only when I scroll datepicker.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You have a callback when you change the date (valueChanged). So it is normal you don't get it when you just dismiss the picker without changing the date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the default date displayed by the date picker once you create a datePicker based on what you want it to be. Because the `default value` of this property is the date when the `UIDatePicker` object is created and that's why whenever you print the value of date picker without spinning, it shows you the current date however if you spin the datePicker, this property is being set properly and you get the right date printed.

```
 //you can use date property to set or get  
 myDatePicker.date = yourFormattedDateHere
```

Setting `date` property **animates** the `date picker` by spinning the wheels to the new date and time, if you don't want any animation to occur when you set the date, use the `setDate(_:animated:)` method, passing false for the animated parameter.